# Is it possible to dynamically change the column name field being called in a select statement?

Tags: sql

There is a table with separate fields for each county.  An example of the field name is "trumbull_written". Is there a way to access the correct counties field by dynamically changing the column name in the select statement with the county name that is passed to the select?  So if I would pass stark to the function then the select statement would get data from column stark_written.

Comment: You have a separate column for every single county?  This sounds like horrible database design...

Comment: I Agree with @Siyual - can you explain the need to have individual columns for each country rather then a table with individual rows for each country - which would make what you are trying to do reasonable and possible?

Comment: I inherited this data base.  I just have to learn to deal with it.

Comment: I did not design the database nor do I have the authority to change it.  Can someone help me with my original question?